# Cache max-age doesn't correctly expire at midnight

Tags: 8, caching

I've got a node which cache should expire every day at midnight. Additionally I've a block showing the same node in another display mode, that also should expire every day at midnight. I thought this would be pretty easy by calculating max-age

**page_cache is already disabled** - dynamic_page_cache is enabled

.module file

```
function wt_lunch_preprocess_node(array &$variables) {
  $node = $variables['node'];
  if ($node->bundle() == 'wt_lunch') {
    $maxAge = strtotime('tomorrow') - strtotime('now');
    $variables['#cache']['max-age'] = $maxAge;
    $today = strtolower(date('l'));
    $variables['max_age'] = $maxAge; // this line is just for debugging
  }
}
```

src/Plugin/Block/MyBlock.php

```
...
  public function build() {
    $maxAge = strtotime('tomorrow') - strtotime('now');
    $emptyResult = [
      '#markup' => '',
      '#cache' => ['max-age' => $maxAge]
    ];

    $node = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()
      ->getStorage('node')
      ->loadByProperties(['type' => 'wt_lunch']);

    if (!$node = reset($node)) {
      return $emptyResult;
    }

    $build = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->view($node, 'special');
    $build['#cache']['max-age'] = $maxAge;
    $build['#attached']['library'][] = 'wt_lunch/daily';
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['wt']['lunch']['timer'] = $node->get('field_lunch_daily_timer')->value;
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['wt']['lunch']['from'] = $node->get('field_lunch_daily_from')->value;
    $build['#attached']['drupalSettings']['wt']['lunch']['until'] = $node->get('field_lunch_daily_until')->value;
    $build['#attributes']['class'][] = 'lunch--daily';
    return $build;
  }
...
```

This works almost every day. Almost. Every 10-15 days the cache does not expire properly and keeps rendering the block from yesterday.

Today the block didn't expire correctly again. I've previously added hidden debug comments in my Twig template, showing cache infos in the rendered HTML:

`{{ date().timestamp }}` ==> `1543194778` (roundabout 1am yesterday)
`{{ max_age }}` ==>  `78422` (see $maxAge in code above, about 23 hours)

So I can verify that `$build['#cache']['max-age']` definitly was correctly calculated, yet I did get the outdated block today at 11am.

Can anybody give me a clue why the `max-age` of the block *sometimes* does not work?

Comment: Are you sure, that there is no other caching between you and your server (Browser, Proxy etc.)? Maybe you should test with wget.

Comment: Not tested, but quite certain not a proxy or browser cache issue, because the problem occurs simultaneously on different devices on different locations.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your flaw is that if there is day where no one views a node of bundle wt_lunch your nodes max age will get out of alignment; thus, your block will also be displaying an outdated node.

For this, don't use preprocess_node, use [Job Scheduler](https://www.drupal.org/project/job_scheduler) or [hook_cron](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!core.api.php/function/hook_cron/8.2.x) instead.

You might also want to utilize the above with [Ultimate Cron](https://www.drupal.org/project/ultimate_cron).

Comment: I would agree, for this case you want something independent of someone having to come view a node.

Comment: @No Sssweat: To understand my mistake: When I do `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->view($node, 'special');` this does NOT trigger `mymodule_preprocess_node()` and so `cache['#max-age']` is not set on the node entity ?

Comment: @Hudri that is probably it, add `\Drupal::logger('my_module')->error('it ran');` to preprocess_node and then run `\Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getViewBuilder('node')->view($node, 'special');` in [Devel](https://www.drupal.org/project/devel) Execute PHP and then check the error log to see if it got recorded.

Comment: I would also use cron, not to set cache max-age, but to invalidate a cache tag you've added in preprocess, so you can enable the internal page cache again. Wouldn't be a good idea to disable it only to solve this issue for one node.